# Why Dumbledore never thought to check on Moaning Myrtle?

Tags: harry-potter

The more times I read the series, the more I come across things that should have been obvious.

In the book Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Harry suddenly guesses that the girl who died in the girls' bathroom 50 years before was Moaning Myrtle.

```
“Ron — that girl who died. Aragog said she was found in a
bathroom,” said Harry, ignoring Neville’s snuffling snores from the
corner. “What if she never left the bathroom? What if she’s still
there?”
Ron rubbed his eyes, frowning through the moonlight. And
then he understood, too.
“You don’t think — not Moaning Myrtle?”
```

And I'm sure his dialogue between Tom Riddle and Albus Dumbledore figures that Dumbledore meant 'since' the death of the girl.

```
“Well, hurry off to bed,” said Dumbledore, giving Riddle exactly
the kind of penetrating stare Harry knew so well. “Best not to
roam the corridors these days. Not since . . .”
He sighed heavily, bade Riddle good night, and strode off.
```

And then as per Professor Binns,

```
Professor Binns looked faintly annoyed.
“The whole thing is arrant nonsense, of course,” he said. “Naturally,
the school has been searched for evidence of such a chamber,
many times, by the most learned witches and wizards. It does not
exist.”
```

Ministry of Magic could have predictably overlooked the clues that unfairly lead to the expulsion of Hagrid. But Dumbledore always thought Hagrid was innocent.In such a case , I just wondered why Dumbledore or any others not make out this obvious connection and question Myrtle as Harry did.

Comment: @MajorStackings : Went through this question and it's answers. My question is specifically why Dumbledore didn't. I completely accept that the ministry could have overlooked the facts. But the likes of Dumbledore could have easily gone to the depths of it.'Great big pair of yellow eyes' clue of Myrtle's itself is sufficient that the eyes didn't belong to Aragog.

Comment: Male staff member, girls' bathroom?? ;-)

Comment: @ThruGog: Do you really think something like that would have stopped Dumbledore from investigating :P?

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil - Maybe for a bit! ;-) But just a bit...

Comment: @ThruGog Dumbledore in the boy's bathrooms would actually cause more of a concern really. Also I'm sure a male staff member came into the girls bathroom in philosopher's stone after the troll incident?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is a dupe, but the biggest answer to this question is the answer to the question [Why didn't the Ministry of Magic ask Moaning Myrtle's ghost about her death?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26464/they-knew-where-she-was-why-didnt-the-ministry-of-magic-ask-moaning-myrtles-g) which explains that Myrtle wouldn't have been much help herself (she didn't know what killed her) and that the case was officially closed. I think the only other Dumbledore-specific things to add are these:

Dumbledore was a headmaster, though a brilliant one, and was rather busy. His school was a vast building and he had an important job. Indeed, don't forget he had other commitments in addition to being the head. We rarely see him outside his office or the Great Hall unless he is dealing with something unusual and specific - apart from the various times he spends several days away from Hogwarts entirely because of his other responsibilities. I suspect that once the case was closed and time had passed, he is unlikely to run into Myrtle or think of her in other situations.

And, JK Rowling herself on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts) says,

> Hogwarts is the most heavily haunted dwelling place in Britain (and this is against stiff competition, as there are more reported ghost sightings/sensings on these damp islands than anywhere else in the world).

While we might not be introduced to very many of the ghosts, given this quote there must be many, many more than we are shown. This may seem like an assumption, but given that the description of the Shrieking Shack and similar, I think it is safe to think that Hogwarts was full of them! Myrtle, as one who keeps a low profile and sticks to a bathroom, is unlikely to draw Dumbledore's attention to reopen the case or start him digging deeper.

Comment: At the time of myrtle' s death D wasn't the headmaster, Dippet was. Also ' too busy'? A girl named Myrtle dies, then a ghost named Myrtle appears who haunts her classmate and in general makes herself a nuisance and the teachers just shrug it off? Or were students dropping dead that often that the staff was stotic about another case?

Comment: @Will Rosenberg - I don't mean he was too busy to get involved at the time. As for 'were students dropping dead that often' - this is Hogwarts we're talking about! Child endangerment is par for the course!

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood.  Later on, in Harrys time sure it was as you said too much ghosts around to make that connection.